# Is there a public roadmap for Redhat JBoss Fuse 7?

Tags: jbossfuse

Is there a public roadmap for Redhat JBoss Fuse 7? I mean other than the ones accessible with a Red Hat Login at https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3253531.

I ask here at SO since the old forum is readonly now, i.e. see https://developer.jboss.org/thread/273716.

Comment: If you have a Red Hat support account, you can open a ticket and ask the support engineer.  This is a fairly common question, you should get back a quick and accurate response.

Comment: ok, so as of now the PDF slides reachable from the link provided by @janstey seems the most up to date roadmap available without a Red Hat support account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The roadmap was presented at last year's Red Hat summit (see PDF slides at https://rh2017.smarteventscloud.com/connect/sessionDetail.ww?SESSION_ID=105088). This should give you a general idea about what will be included. Keep in mind that the specifics change from sprint to sprint so if you are interested about a particular feature or bug fix, please get in touch.